# How to properly install OpenCV on Ubuntu?

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to install OpenCV 2.2.0 on Ubuntu 12.04, but I'm getting this error:

```
torul@torul-HP-Compaq-8200-Elite-CMT-PC:~/OpenCV-2.2.0/opencv.build$ make 

make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/rand.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Could anyone tell me, what am I doing wrong (why am I getting the above error) ?

Comment: Since OpenCV 2.3.1 is already packaged in Ubuntu 12.04, is there any reason why you want to install a much older version?

Comment: And if you really want to build this ancient version manually, you better include what steps you performed before running `make`.

Answer (score 1):

***Ubuntu Installation*** :->

1. Install virtualenv :->

> `sudo apt-get install virtualenv`

2. Then install python which you want to use in your virtual environment from this [link](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/).
3. Make virtual environment :->

> `virtualenv --python = $(which python) environment name`

Replace "**environment name**" with the name you want keep in your PC.

“**which python**” command will return the path of python which you want to use in your new environment.

4. To enter in new virtual environment :-> Run below commands in terminal -

> `source envname/bin/activate`

5. Run below command to ensure pip in installed in your system :->

> `sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip`

6. To install opencv :->

> `pip install opencv-python`

***Enjoy computer-vision………***

“A lot of the future of search is going to be about pictures. Computer vision technology is going to be a big deal”.

**Ben Silbermann**

.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you what you're doing wrong, but have you tried following the OpenCV installation instructions for ubuntu?  [They can be found here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV#Installation)

It doesn't seem to include a make step.